# Pie charts to a JPanel netbeans

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, frame, pie-chart

I am trying to add some graphical charts to my ui the ui has a seperate button to view pie chart when it click the chart should appear in a panel i tried this code

```
DefaultPieDataset defaultPieDataset = new DefaultPieDataset();
        defaultPieDataset.setValue("Monday", new Integer(0));
        defaultPieDataset.setValue("Tuesday", new Integer(2));
        defaultPieDataset.setValue("Wednesday", new Integer(1));
        defaultPieDataset.setValue("Thursday", new Integer(2));
        defaultPieDataset.setValue("Friday", new Integer(0));
        defaultPieDataset.setValue("Saturday", new Integer(3));
        defaultPieDataset.setValue("Sunday", new Integer(2));
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart(Daily Usage", defaultPieDataset, true, true, true);
        PiePlot p = (PiePlot)chart.getPlot();
        p.setDirection(Rotation.CLOCKWISE);
        ChartFrame frame = new ChartFrame("Daily Usage", chart);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

but this uses a frame not a panel is there a any way to get this o display in a jpanel. I am not using any frameworks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the chart to a [ChartPanel](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html) and instead of a frame, you will have a `JPanel`.

Here is a complete example of a `ChartPanel` inside a `JFrame` which contains typical JPanel as well:

```
public class ChartPanelExample extends JFrame {
    public ChartPanelExample() {
        super("");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

        JButton button = new JButton("Something");
        topPanel.add(button);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("This is another JPanel");
        topPanel.add(label);

        add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        DefaultPieDataset defaultPieDataset = new DefaultPieDataset();
        defaultPieDataset.setValue("Monday", new Integer(0));
        defaultPieDataset.setValue("Tuesday", new Integer(2));
        defaultPieDataset.setValue("Wednesday", new Integer(1));
        defaultPieDataset.setValue("Thursday", new Integer(2));
        defaultPieDataset.setValue("Friday", new Integer(0));
        defaultPieDataset.setValue("Saturday", new Integer(3));
        defaultPieDataset.setValue("Sunday", new Integer(2));
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart("Daily Usage", defaultPieDataset, true, true, true);
        PiePlot p = (PiePlot) chart.getPlot();
        p.setDirection(Rotation.CLOCKWISE);

        ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);

        add(chartPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setLocationByPlatform(true);
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new ChartPanelExample().setVisible(true));
    }
}
```

Comment: `ChartPanel frame = new ChartPanel(chart);
        jPanel9 = frame;` I tied this but this did not work

Comment: @ProgrammingTutorials What do you mean "this did not work"?

Comment: The chart did not appear in the jPanel